# what does "write_gcm: Server response (CollectdTimeseriesRequest) contains errors:#012" mean?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i checked something in my syslog of my VM and i found this message:

write_gcm: Server response (CollectdTimeseriesRequest) contains errors:#012{#012  "summary": {#012    "totalPointCount": 2,#012    "errors": [#012      {#012        "status": {#012          "code": 3,#012

and i don't know what it means, please someone could help me?

I have checked every documentation possible, but doesn't give results

Comment: Would you please make sure that the Ops Agent is updated and confirm what is the version of the agent and the OS?

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/installation#upgrade